# Cost of using multiple render targets

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu

I am using glsl as a framework for GPGPU for real-time image-processing. I am currently trying to "shave off" a few more milliseconds to make my application real-time. Here's the basic setup:

I take an input image, calculate several transformations of it, and then output a result image. For instance, Let the input image be `I`. Then the one fragment shader calculates `f(I);` the second calculates `g(I);` and the last one calculates `h(f(I),g(I))`.

My question is regarding efficiently calculating `f(I),g(I)`: does it matter if I use 2 separate fragment shaders (and therefore 2 rendering passes), or if I use a single fragment shader with 2 outputs? Will the latter run faster? I have mostly found discussions about the "how-to"; not about the performance.

### Edit

Thanks for the replies so far. Following several remarks, here's an example for my use-case with some more details:

I want a to filter the rows of image `I` with a 1-d filter; and also filter the rows of the squared image (each pixel is squared).  `f(I) = filter rows` and `g(I) = square and filter rows`:

`shader1: (input image) I --> filter rows --> I_rows (output image)`

`shader2: (input image) I --> square pixels and filter rows--> I^2_rows (output image)`

The question is: **will writing a single shader that does both operations be faster than running these two shaders one after the other?** @derhass suggests that the answer is positive, because of accessing the same texture locations and enjoying locality. But if it wasn't for the texture-locality: would I still be enjoying a performance boost? or is a single shader rendering to two outputs basically equivalent to two render passes?

Comment: How do you mean a "single fragment shader with 2 outputs"?

Comment: I'm with @zero298 in that I don't understand what you mean by a single fragment shader with two outputs. If I understand you correctly, then F(I) would render into one texture, G(I) would render into another, and H(F(I), G(I)) would render to screen. Have three FBO, two of which point their color attachment to a texture render buffer.

Comment: Just a note: when you use `I` as an identifier and you write a question, then highlight it so that it is easier to differ between the identifier `I`  and _I (you)_.

Comment: To go a little bit further, depending on what you need from the output, you *could* hypothetically only use one frag shader, but only if you can fit all the information you need into a single color channel.  I usually shove depth data into the `a` of `rgba` when I don't need transparency.  But since your doing image processing, you probably need all the color you can get, in which case consider @Freddy 's suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using multiple render passes is usually slower than using one pass with MRT output, but this will also depend on your situation.

As I understand it, both `f(I)` and `g(I)` sample the input image `I`, and if each samples the same (or closely neighboring) loactions, you can greatly profit from the texture cache *between* the different operations - you have to sample the input texture just once, instead of two times with the multipass approach.

Taking this approach one step further: Do you even need the intermediate results `f(I)` and `g(I)` separately? Maybe you could just put `h(f(I),g(I))` directly onto one shader, so you do neither need multiple passes and MRTs. If you want to be able to dyanmically combine your operations, you can still use that apporach and programatically combine different shader code parts dynamically to implement the operations (where possible), and use multiple passes only where absolutely necessary.

**EDIT**

As the question has been updated in the meantime, I think I can give some more specific answers:

What I said so far, especially about putting h(f(I),g(f(I)) into one shader is only a good idea if h (or f and g) will not need any neighboring pixels. If h is a nxn filter kernel, you would have to access nxn different input texels, and since those inputs are not directly known, you would have to calculate f and g for each of them. If both f and h are filter kernels, the effective filter size of the compound operation will be greater, and it is much better to calculate the intermediate results first and use multiple passes.

Looking at the specific issue you describe, it comes down to this.

If you use two separate shaders in the most naive way, you rendering will look like this.

1. use the shader1
2. select some output color buffer
3. draw a quad
4. use shader2
5. select some different color buffer
6. draw a quad

Every draw call has its overhead. The GL will have to do some extra validation. Switching the shaders might be the most expensive extra step here compared to the combined shader approach, as it might force a GPU pipeline flush. Als, for each draw call, you have the vertex processing, rasterization, and per fragment attribute interolation operations. With just one shader, lot's of this overhead is going away, and the per-fragment calculations described so far can be "shared" for both filters.

> But if it wasn't for the texture-locality: would I still be enjoying a
>   performance boost?

Because of the stuff I said so far, and specific to the shaders you presented, I tend to say: yes. But the effect will be very small to neglegible if we ignore the texture acesses here, especially if we assume reasonable high resolution images so that the relative overhead compared to the total amount of work appearts small. I would at least say that using a single pass MRT setup will not be slower. However, only benchmarking/profiling the very specific implementation on a specific GPU will give a definitive answer.

Why did I say "the shaders you presented". Because in both cases, you do the image squaring in one shader. You could split that into two different shaders and renderpasses also. In that case, you would get additional overhead (to the already mentioned) for writing the intermediate results, and having to read that back. However, since you run a filter over the intermediate resulte, you do not have to square any input texel more than once, but in the combined approach, you do. If the squaring operation is expensive enough, and your filter size is big enough, you could in theory save more time than is introduced by the overhead of multiple passes. Again, only benchmarking/profiling cann tell you where the break even would lie.

I have done some benchmarking with MRT vs. multiple render passes myself in the past, although the image processing operations I was interested in are a bit different from yours. What I found is that in such scenarios, the texture access is the key factor, and you can hide a lot of other calculations (like squaring a color value) in the texture access latency. I think that your "But if it wasn't for the texture-locality" is a bit unrealistic, since it is the major contribution to the overall running time. And it isn't just the locality, it is also the number of texture accesses in total: With your multipe-shader approach, an imge of size `w*h`, and a 1D filter of size `n`, you will end up with `2*w*h*n` texture accesses overall, while with the combined approach, you will just have reduced to `*w*h*n`, and that will make a huge difference in the past.

For a AMD FirePro V9800,image size of 1920x1080, and just copying the pixels to two output buffers by rendering textured quds, I got with two passes: ~0,320ms (even without switching shaders) vs 1 pass MRT: ~0,230ms. So execution time was reduced by "only" 30%, but this was with just one texutre fetch per shader invocation. With filter kernels, I'd expect to see this figure getting closer to 50% reduction with increasing kernel size (but I haven't measured that, though).

Comment: thanks for your answer @derhass. I clarified a bit my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Let us ignore any potential benefits from hardware-specific things like data cache, register re-use, etc. that might occur if you do your entire algorithm in a single shader invocation and focus entirely on algorithm complexity for a minute.

A [Gaussian Blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) on a 2D image is a [separable filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) (X and Y can be blurred as a much simpler series of 1D blurs), and you can actually get better performance if you split the horizontal and vertical application into two passes.

### Consider the complexity of ***two*** 1D blurs vs. ***one*** 2D blur in Big O:

#### Two-Pass Gaussian Blur <sub>(Two 1D blurs):</sub>

[image: Two-Pass]

#### Single-Pass Gaussian Blur <sub>(Single 2D blur):</sub>

[image: Single-Pass]

Deferred shading is another example. Instead of one massive loop over all lights in a single-pass, many implementations will do one pass per-light shading only the area of the screen that each individual light actually covers.

Multi-pass is not always a bad thing, when it simplifies your algorithm as in the case of a separable filter or light coverage, it is often ***good***.

Your results may vary, but if you can show an appreciable difference in algorithm complexity in Big O notation using one approach over the other, it is worth exploring the run-time performance of both implementations.

Comment: If we use linear sampling at the center of 4 pixels in one pass Gaussian, which should have the same number of sampling for two pass Gaussian filter (using sampling at the center of 2 pixels).